# Change the view (main window) for my application in IB

Tags: xcode

I am quite new to Objective-C, Xcode, IB, DashCode, etc.  I am working on a problem set and need to change the background color of the main window (the view) for my project.  I have done some searching and it appears I would need to add an NSWindow and backgroundColorwell possibly to have it changed but other than that I am clueless.

The window I am referring to is the one upon which you build upon with library elements.  I wish it were simple to specify a color for that window.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little difficult to answer this question without seeing how you've set things up. If you're using XCode 4.2 and storyboards, it's very simple. Just change the background color of the view. (See far right of screen shot).

You can also programmatically set the background.

For instance:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Here's the screenshot for using the storyboard. Select your view, then under attributes inspector on the right, choose your color.

[image]

If you're still having a problem, just provide more information on your project and I'll be glad to elaborate!

Comment: Or `self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];` if that's what you're after.